# How to count how many times each LED has turned on?

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

I have a function that turns on 1 random LED out of 8, based on a randomly generated number in the range of 256.

I need to count how many times each LED has turned on and use this number to turn on each LED as many times as it was turned on randomly.

I am using a `for` loop to run it 100 times:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
  randomLED();
}
```

and this is my function:

```cpp
void randomLED() {

    int index = random(256);
    int del3 = 100;

    if (index <= 31) {
        digitalWrite(ledPins[0], HIGH);
        delay(del3);
        digitalWrite(ledPins[0], LOW);
    }
    else if (index >= 32 && index <= 63) {
        digitalWrite(ledPins[1], HIGH);
        delay(del3);
        digitalWrite(ledPins[1], LOW);
    }
    else if (index >= 64 && index <= 95) {
        digitalWrite(ledPins[2], HIGH);
        delay(del3);
        digitalWrite(ledPins[2], LOW);
    }
    else if (index >= 96 && index <= 127) {
        digitalWrite(ledPins[3], HIGH);
        delay(del3);
        digitalWrite(ledPins[3], LOW);
    }
    else if (index >= 128 && index <= 159) {
        digitalWrite(ledPins[4], HIGH);
        delay(del3);
        digitalWrite(ledPins[4], LOW);
    }
    else if (index >= 160 && index <= 191) {
        digitalWrite(ledPins[5], HIGH);
        delay(del3);
        digitalWrite(ledPins[5], LOW);
    }
    else if (index >= 192 && index <= 223) {
        digitalWrite(ledPins[6], HIGH);
        delay(del3);
        digitalWrite(ledPins[6], LOW);
    }
    else if (index >= 224 && index <= 256) {
        digitalWrite(ledPins[7], HIGH);
        delay(del3);
        digitalWrite(ledPins[7], LOW);
    }

    delay(del3);
    randomSeed(analogRead(1));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Roughly like this (untested):

Make a global array to keep count of how often each LED has turned on, like so:

```cpp
int count[8] = {0};
```

In your `randomLED()` function, in every `if (index` etc, increment the counter for each `ledPins[x]`, where `x` is the number of the LED, like so:

```cpp
count[x] += 1;
```

When the looping is done, you'll have counted how often each LED has been turned on.

You can now use that number to blink each LED:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < count[i]; j++) {
    digitalWrite(ledPins[i], HIGH);
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(ledPins[i], LOW);
    delay(100);
  }
}
```

Also, don't declare index twice:

```cpp
int index;
index = random(256);
int index; // <====== Remove this line
```

You may want to consider using `random(8)` instead of `random(256)` to make it easier to simplify your code.